# SmartGWT - How to programmatically trigger collapse/expand action of resizebar

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I am working with smartgwt 3.0.

I would like to access the resizebar programmatically to collapse or expand its target panel. I can't seem to find any API like

> canvas.getResizeBar();

How would I do that?

Is there a way to perform something like
Code:

> canvas.setCollapsed(boolean);

?

Where true indicates collapsing the target canvas and false indicates expanding the target canvas.

I think the alternative is to explicitly use setWidth of the target canvas to expand/collapse the target. I am trying to avoid having to do that as I would have to replicate all the states and memorised widths of the target canvas. I should not reinvent the wheel when the state of the target canvas is already kept somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Just hide() the component the resizeBar would collapse and the resizeBar will reflect the component's new state.

Comment: When the panel is hidden programmatically, the resizebar is stuck and no longer usable by user to expand the panel. And then when I tried to use a resizebar targeted at a third panel, the third panel would not collapse - but its widgets got resized.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a left and a right panel like this (inside another root panel) :

```
VLayout leftMainGUI = new VLayout();
leftMainGUI.setWidth(200);
leftMainGUI.setShowResizeBar(true);

VLayout rightMainGUI = new VLayout();
rightMainGUI.setWidth(200);
```

If you change the width of the rightMainGui, the bar should move. Are you sure than using hide() and show() with the rightMainGui doesn't work ?